# Не работают теги html в php

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование, веб-сервер

Вот такое работает:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
?>
```

Такое уже НЕ работает:

```
<?php
<p>echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];</p>
?>
```

Comment: оно не не работает - это ошибка синтаксиса

Comment: так они и не должны так работать, если надо обернуть в теги, то надо так: `<p><?php ... ?></p>`

Comment: ^ ага. или даже так `<p><?= $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ?></p>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В <?php ?> имеет место только коду php, что бы там был html нужно сделать так:

```
<?php
echo '<p>' . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . '</p>';
?>
```

или так:

`<p><?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; ?></p>`