# PHP. Передача параметров между страницами

Tags: php

Подскажите, как сделать правильно такую конструкцию. 
Имеются `index.php` и `sometext.php`. На странице `index.php` есть форма:

```
<HTML> 
<HEAD> 
<TITLE>Отчет</TITLE>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</HEAD> 
<BODY> 
<H3> <center><font color="#1E90FF">Отчет</font></H3>                                 
<center> 
<table width="1" border="0"> 
     <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"> 
    <tr><td width="50%"><i>Планируемый адрес установки:</i></td><td align="right"><input type="text" name="install_address" maxlength="40" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['install_address'])) echo $_POST['install_address']; else echo "";?>"></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><i>Примечание:</i><br><textarea cols="50" rows="3" name="free_descr" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['free_descr'])) echo $_POST['free_descr']; else echo "";?>"></textarea></td> 
</tr><tr><td colspan="2"><center><input type="submit" value="Генерировать"></center></td></tr>         
</form> 
</table> 
</center>


<?php

if ($_POST['free_descr']) {
$install_address = $_POST['install_address'];
$freedescr = $_POST['free_descr'];
echo <<<EOT
Полученные параметры:<br>

<b>Планируемый адрес установки:</b> $install_address<br>  
<b>Примечание:</b> $freedescr<br>
EOT;

$sometext='sometext.php';

echo file_get_contents($sometext);

};
?>
</BODY> 
</HTML>
```

Содержимое файла `sometext.php`:

```
<?php
## Place<br>
Место установки $install_address<br>
## Descr<br>
Примечание $freedescr<br>
Отправлено<br>
?>
```

Я пытаюсь добиться того, чтобы содержимое `sometext.php` выводилось на `index.php`. Содержимое выводится , но выводится как есть , т. е. `$install_address` и `$freedescr` не изменяются, а так и пишутся `$freedescr` и `$install_address`.

Как сделать так, чтобы содержимое менялось?

Comment: Вы уверены что привели правильный код `sometext.php`? Такой должен вызвать ошибку.

Comment: Во-первых прочитайте свеженькое буквально сегодня..... http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/516862/191482  ........а во вторых.... где `echo` ?

Comment: @alias Ошибка не появляется . 2 Алексей Шиманский, я не силен в php , не могли бы Вы указать где не хватает 'echo'?

Comment: `<?php echo" ..... "; ?>`

Comment: Как я понимаю в случае с `file_get_contents` придется писать `str_replace` тех переменных, которые в `sometext.php`, потому, что все что достал `file_get_contents` получается обычной строкой/текстом....... вам нужен скорее `include` для таких целей......при этом не забыв сделать `<?php echo $install_address ?>` и `<?php echo $freedescr?>`  а первый тег и конечный наоборот, удалить

Comment: Алексей Шиманский , спасибо , работает!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте через функцию Include_once() или include. 
в инете примеры есть